# How to provide custom type in jest unit test?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I am having a S3 service with following code.

```
import { IAWS } from '../AWS';
import { S3 } from 'aws-sdk';
export interface S3ServiceConstructor {
  pathDelimiter?: string;
}

export class S3Service {
  private s3: S3;
  private readonly pathDelimiter: string;

  constructor(
    { pathDelimiter }: S3ServiceConstructor,
    options?: S3.Types.ClientConfiguration
  ) {
    this.pathDelimiter = pathDelimiter || '/';
    this.s3 = new IAWS.S3(options);
  }
}
```

Below is my test file code

```
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';

export interface S3ServiceConstructor {
    pathDelimiter?: string;
}

import { S3Service } from './s3.service';

describe('S3 Service', () => {
    let service: S3Service;

    const mockS3Instance = {
        upload: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
        promise: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
        catch: jest.fn()
    }

    jest.mock('aws-sdk', () => {
        return jest.fn(() => mockS3Instance)
    });

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [
                S3Service,
                provide: [] // HERE?
            ]
        }).compile();

        service = moduleRef.get<S3Service>(S3Service);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

    it('getXYZ should be called with correct parameters', async () => {
        // ....
    });
});
```

How can I provide the `s3Constructor` in the test file?
It is a type and I am getting following error when I put it there.

[image]

Comment: please show us how you're registering `S3Service` in the app, not in the test suite. That will dictates how you will replace its dependencies with fake doubles.

Comment: I am not sure if I got you right. But, the first code snippet is of my S3Service in the app for which I am writing test file.

Comment: in nestjs apps, we register providers for some nestjs module by adding it to the `providers` array. Show us how you're doing that for `S3Service` outside of your test file.

Comment: You can't use a type in value position.

Comment: @AluanHaddad So how do I test this part? Or how can I create the TestingModule here?

Comment: You have to provide a value. It is not possible nor has it ever been possible to provide a type. When you provide a class for example, you are not providing a type but rather the value that has the same name as the instance type but which is actually the class object itself.

Comment: As for how you can provide a value for that injection parameter in the service, you need to create an injection token and register it so that your app will actually be able to construct the service outside of tests. You can then use that token in the tests